# jsonpickle and float decoding (demjson)

Tags: python, json

How can I set the jsonpickle such that all floats are decoded as `floats` and not `decimal.Decimals`:

```
import jsonpickle
import demjson


jsonpickle.set_preferred_backend("demjson")

a="0.1231231231237816387163871623"
jsonpickle.decode(a)
```

this is decoded into `Decimal('0.1231231231237816387163871623')` which I do not want...
Is there a solution?

Comment: I was using an non up to date version 0.8 of jsonpickle which does not have a function set_decoder_options

Answer (score 0):

The following is possible with jsonpickle 0.9 from github:

```
import jsonpickle
import demjson

jsonpickle.load_backend("demjson","encode","decode",ValueError)
jsonpickle.set_preferred_backend("demjson")
jsonpickle.set_decoder_options("demjson",decode_float=float)

a="3.198347901834750918374509813745019283091820398123"
jsonpickle.decode(a)
```